# Insert row with column value same as Auto Increment value

Tags: mysql, connection-pooling, auto-increment

I'm filling table which contain ID field (auto-increment) and some other fields.
One of the requirements is to copy auto-increment value to another field in the same table.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
INSERT INTO testtable (testtable.NAME, testtable.lastID) VALUES ('xxx',(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'testtable'
AND table_schema = DATABASE( )))
```

I'm wondering it this thread safe? Will this work properly when there are multiple connections and they are all performing insert statement?

Comment: Better way is to setup triggers in `after insert on table`

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it. What's wrong with LAST _INSERT_ID?

Comment: I see flaw in your entire approach.  What would happen if you delete a record?  Then, the entire chain of `lastID` to current ID would be broken.  How would you maintain this?  Do you really need to do what you are doing here?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: The first idea was to use trigger but I don't need always to update this field, only is special cases. LAST_INSERT_ID is not option. MySQL verison is 5.6.17

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an After insert trigger to copy one field to another it's the best way.

```
--
-- Triggers `testtable`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_field`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update_field` AFTER INSERT ON `testtable`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO testtable 
    update testtable
           set lastID = new.id 
            WHERE testtable.id = new.id
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger. You can set NEW. Values on a before trigger.and I assume that the insert into is a typo